# How can I configure an activemq queue to not use the default dead letter queue for expired messages

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to implement a strategy where when messages in an activemq queue expire, instead of being moved to the default dead letter queue ActiveMQ.DLQ, they will go another dead letter queue.

My application uses camel-context for routing and bean definition. I have looked at http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html and I am not sure how to implement the individualDeadLetterStrategy.

I thought to try creating a Redelivery Policy bean and add that to my connection factory but I don't see a property for dead letter strategy here http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html

I also considered using an error handler but my use case is not an error scenario.

My question is how do I configure/specify a dead-letter-queue for an individual queue.

I have configured my application to produce to the queue like this

```
        <route id="myRoute">
            <from uri="direct:insertToQueue" />
            <doTry>
                <bean ref="processorBean" method="getQueueRequest"/>
                <to uri="activemqProducer:queue:myQueue" />
                <doCatch>
                    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                    <handled>
                        <constant>true</constant>
                    </handled>
                    <bean method="getExceptionResponse" ref="processorBean" />
                </doCatch>
            </doTry>
        </route>
```

the activemq component, "activemqProducer" is defined like this:

```
    <bean id="activemqProducer" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfigProducer"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsConfigProducer" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration" scope="prototype">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsFactoryProducer"/>
        <property name="transacted" value="false"/>
        <property name="deliveryPersistent" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeToLive" value="5000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsFactoryProducer" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop" scope="prototype">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="maxConnections" value="${jms.maximum.connection}" />
        <property name="maximumActiveSessionPerConnection" value="${jms.maximum.active}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id ="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL"><value>${message.broker}</value></property>
        <property name="userName"><value>${message.broker.username}</value></property>
        <property name="password"><value>${message.broker.password}</value></property>
        <property name="optimizeAcknowledge" value="true"/>

        <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

How can I include configurations for an individual dead letter queue for myQueue. If thats not possible, then how can I tell activemq to keep expired messages in myQueue

Answer (score 1):

The [page you mention](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html) explains how to configure the DLQs in the broker configuration.

For example this configuration taken from the mentioned page configures the broker so that a non-deliverable message of a queue named `MyMessageQueue` goes to  **`DLQ.MyMessageQueue` instead of the standard `ActiveMQ.DLQ`**

```
<destinationPolicy>
<policyMap>
  <policyEntries>
    <policyEntry queue=">">
      <deadLetterStrategy>
        <individualDeadLetterStrategy queuePrefix="DLQ." useQueueForQueueMessages="true"/>
      </deadLetterStrategy>
    </policyEntry>
  </policyEntries>
</policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>
```

Probably not very clear is the **destination wildcard** `queue=">"` that means "all queues". See [this page](http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html) for an explanation of these wildcards.

> Due to the fact that destination configuration is done with help of these wildcards, it is advisable to **name your queues and topics in a way that allows you "group" destinations** with special configuration needs with such wildcards.

Comment: Yes. I saw that. I was hoping to configure it without modifying the activemq.xml file but I couldn’t figure a way around it so that’s what I ended up doing

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of ActiveMQ (eg Artemis), there is a way to define different expiry address (depending on regex on queue name):

```
<address-setting match="com.company.demo.MyQueue">
   <expiry-address>com.company.demo.EXP.MyQueue</expiry-address>
</address-setting>
```

More info at:
https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/message-expiry.html

Comment: This would require migrating my ActiveMQ which I’m not at liberty to do.